# не работает go mod tidy

Tags: golang, зависимости

добавляю зависимости в свой проект, запускаю go mod tidy, падает куча ошибок по типу

```
/GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew" should not have @version
```

```
server/GOROOT/test imports
    : malformed import path "": empty string
server/GOROOT/test imports
    : malformed import path "\x00": invalid char '\x00'
server/GOROOT/test imports
    "`a`": malformed import path "\"`a`\"": invalid char '"'
server/GOROOT/test imports
    /foo: "/foo" is not a package path; see 'go help packages'
server/GOROOT/test imports
    \"a\": malformed import path "\\\"a\\\"": invalid char '\\'
```

```
bogus: malformed import path "\nbogus": invalid char '\n'
server/GOROOT/test/fixedbugs imports
    unicode//utf8: malformed import path "unicode//utf8": double slash
server/GOROOT/test/fixedbugs/bug083.dir imports
    ./bug0: "./bug0" is relative, but relative import paths are not supported in module mode
server/GOROOT/test/fixedbugs/bug133.dir imports
    ./bug1: "./bug1" is relative, but relative import paths are not supported in module mode
server/GOROOT/test/fixedbugs/bug160.dir imports
    ./x: "./x" is relative, but relative import paths are not supported in module mode
server/GOROOT/test/fixedbugs/bug282.dir imports
```

при этом go run и go build работает.
проверял на версиях го 1.18 и 1.20, результат одинаковый, зависимости добавлял каждый раз заново через go get.

```
module server

go 1.18

require (
    github.com/bytedance/sonic v1.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/chenzhuoyu/base64x v0.0.0-20221115062448-fe3a3abad311 // indirect
    github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype v1.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/gin-contrib/cors v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/locales v0.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.18.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.14.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.7.1 // indirect
    github.com/goccy/go-json v0.10.2 // indirect
    github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v5 v5.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.12 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/cpuid/v2 v2.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.19 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2 v2.0.8 // indirect
    github.com/twitchyliquid64/golang-asm v0.15.1 // indirect
    github.com/ugorji/go/codec v1.2.11 // indirect
    golang.org/x/arch v0.3.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.10.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.8.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.9.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.30.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

я хочу сделать вызов go mod tidy при каждом перезапуске docker контейнера, чтоб подтягивались и удалялись зависимости, если они добавлялись/удалялись/изменялись в go.mod

Где у меня ошибка?

Comment: Удалите каталог `GOROOT/test`. Команды `go build` и `go run` его игнорируют, а `go mod tidy` в этот каталог заглядывает и ломается на файлах оттуда. Либо переименуйте его - go [игнорирует каталоги](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns), которые начинаются с `.` или `_`, а так же каталог с именем `testdata`.

Comment: но почему он валится на тестах?разве так должно быть?
я удалил папку ради интереса, многие ошибки пропали, но остались по типу этой
/GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew" should not have @version

Comment: попробовал сделать go mod tidy на пустом проекте без зависимостей, тоже самое, ругается на папку test